# Extension method on lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

I have a helper method which gets the name of a property defined by a lambda which works as below:

```
ExpressionUtil.GetName((Thing t) => t.Property); // returns "Property"
```

I would like to turn this into an extension method so the syntax would be of the form:

```
((Thing t) => t.Property).GetName(); // wont compile : operator '.' cannot be applies to operand of type 'lambda expression'
```

However I cant seem to do this as `((Thing t) => t.Property)` is a lambda (not an expression or Func yet). Is there any way to write an extension method which applies directly to a lambda? If not why is this a bad thing to do?

Comment: You could cast it too, but that would look horrible. :)

Comment: @rynah Yeah i was trying to avoid the cast if possible, the whole point of putting it in an extension method is to make it simpler to read which you kinda lose with the cast code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, because a lambda expression has no type by itself; its type is determined by the context (e.g. if you assign it to a delegate variable or pass it as an argument to a method).

Since `((Thing t) => t.Property)` doesn't have a type, you can't call an extension method on it, because the compiler doesn't know which extension methods are valid candidates.

You can, however, declare a variable and call the extension method on it:

```
Func<Thing, OtherThing> func = t => t.Property;
string name = func.GetName();
```

Comment: Its sounding like my best bet is to stick with a helper for this which makes me a little sad. anything more seems to get more complex than its worth

Answer (score 1):

you may create an extension method on an Action at the low cost of having a introducing instantiation.
I sometimes use it and the code is readable.
The reason this code exists is less elegant, a rotten NAS :-[

```
new Action(() =>
    {
        if (File.Exists(newFullPath))
            File.Delete(newFullPath);

        File.Move(oldFullPath, newFullPath);
    })
.Try(attemps: 2, exceptionValidator: (exception, attempt, attempts) =>
    {
        var throwIt = (attempt == attempts);
        if (!throwIt)
            Thread.Sleep(500);

        // .. tracing ./. throw
        return (throwIt);
    });
```

Just in case ... even if post not young.