# Unable to make an extension method work on a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods

Consider the example below. I am able to make a call to an extension method for a delegate if first I **define a variable** of that delegate type. But I cannot call that extension method on a delegate which is **passed as an argument**. I don't get why it works the first time but doesn't work the second. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static class Extender
{
    public static Func<String, String> Compose(this Func<String, String> outer, Func<String, String> inner)
    {
        return input => outer(inner(input));
    }
}
public class Demo
{
    public void WillingToTakeStringToStringDelegate(Func<String, String> map)
    {
        // blah
    }
    public void RunMe()
    {
        Func<String, String> outer = x => "(outer: " + x + ")";

        // this works:
        var composition = outer.Compose(x => "(inner: " + x + ")");
        Trace.Write(composition("!"));  // ---> (outer: (inner: !))

        // this doesn't work:
        this.WillingToTakeStringToStringDelegate(
            (x => "(outer: " + x + ")").Compose(y => "(inner: " + y + ")")
        );
    }
}
```

## UPDATE

**for @philologon**

As long as you don't mind having to assign your lambdas to variables then yes, you can use this method for creating partial applications of functions (currying) like a boss:

```
public static class CurryingHelper
{
    public static Func<X> Apply<A, X>(this Func<A, X> fun, A a)
    {
        return () => fun(a);
    }
    public static Func<B, X> Apply<A, B, X>(this Func<A, B, X> fun, A a)
    {
        return b => fun(a, b);
    }
    public static Func<B, C, X> Apply<A, B, C, X>(this Func<A, B, C, X> fun, A a)
    {
        return (b, c) => fun(a, b, c);
    }
    public static Func<B, C, D, X> Apply<A, B, C, D, X>(this Func<A, B, C, D, X> fun, A a)
    {
        return (b, c, d) => fun(a, b, c, d);
    }

    // etc... 
}

public class Demo
{
    public void RunMe()
    {
        Func<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32> func = (a, b, c) => a - b + c;
        var funcA1 = func.Apply(1);
        Trace.Write(funcA1(2, 3));               // --> 2
        Trace.Write(funcA1.Apply(2).Apply(3)()); // --> 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Great question. It never occurred to me that extension methods could be added to Func. Thanks for asking and introducing me to a new idea :)

Comment: Side note: you can significantly simply sample by using other couple of types like  `double`/`int`: `Compose(this double v)`... `1.Compose()`.

Comment: @DavidArno, look at F# it's all about making compositions of functions, it's very mind bending after years in imperative C# programming

Comment: @AlekseyBykov, I've started learning F# and have toyed with function composition. I've even tried to create a similar ideas with C#. I never thought to try it this way though. You have enlightened me...

Comment: C# is fine for mind bending too :) - My favorite reading - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, the better way around would be using generics like `public static Func<T, T> Compose(this Func<T, T> outer, Func<T, T> inner)
    {
        return input => outer(inner(input));
    }`

Comment: My suggestion with `double`/`int` was to show that you need exact match for extension to apply, but with lambdas the more important reason (as covered in all answers) is lack of concrete type at all (should be dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328231/extension-method-on-lambda-expression, but this one have much better answers now).

Comment: So can this approach, putting an extension method on a delegate, be used to simulate Partial Function evaluation or Currying in C#?  (Note:  As I ask this, I do not know what those are at a deep level, just a superficial level.  That is why I need to ask such a question.)

Comment: @philologon, you don't need extension methods to do so, consider: `public Func<A, C, Result> CreatePartialApplication<A, B, C, D, Result> (Func<A, B, C, D, Result> fun, B b, D d)
        {
            return (a, c) => fun(a, b, c, d);
        }` I mean it would be nice if the extension methods worked this way, because if they did then we would have a nicer syntax for doing the same. However it turned out they only work with a 'hint' which is as ugly as hell, so no better syntax. Sorry.

Comment: @philologon, check out the update to the question

Answer (score 13):

There is nothing wrong with the conception, only some technical problems with the execution.

The point is that `x => "(outer: " + x + ")"` is *not* a delegate without context: it is a lambda expression that could either correspond to a delegate (of *some* type) or even to an expression tree. Therefore the type has to be explicitly or implicitly declared, e.g.

```
// this works:
this.WillingToTakeStringToStringDelegate(
    ((Func<string, string>)(x => "(outer: " + x + ")")).Compose(...)
);
```

This is the exact same reason why you cannot assign lambda functions to implicitly typed variables, e.g.

```
var f1 = (string s) => "Hello " + s;                   // does not work
Func<string, string> f2 = (string s) => "Hello " + s;  // works fine
```

Answer (score 11):

Lambda expressions in C# do not have types by themselves. For example, you can assign the lambda expression `x => x != 0` to `Predicate<int>`, `Func<int, bool>`, `Func<long, bool>` or `YourCustomDelegate`.

So, whenever you use a lambda expression, you need to provide a hint to the compiler what delegate type should be used.

*Examples:*

- This works. The hint is the type of the variable `outer`.

  ```
  Func<String, String> outer = x => "(outer: " + x + ")";
  ```
- This works. The hint is the type of the parameter `inner` of the `Compose` method.

  ```
  var composition = outer.Compose(x => "(inner: " + x + ")");
  ```
- This doesn't work, because no hint is provided for `(x => "(outer: " + x + ")")`:

  ```
  this.WillingToTakeStringToStringDelegate(
      (x => "(outer: " + x + ")").Compose(y => "(inner: " + y + ")")
  );
  ```

Answer (score 8):

The other answers are correct; I just wanted to note that the design team *deliberately* chose that extension methods *not* work on any expression that had no type -- so, no extension methods on lambdas, anonymous methods, null or method groups, or any dynamic expression.

In fact it goes farther than that; the expression on the left of the dot must be convertible to the first parameter by an *identity*, *implicit reference* or *boxing* conversion. So in other words:

```
enum E { }
static class Ext
{
    public static E X(this E e) { return e; }
}

// Legal
E e1 = 0;
// Legal
E e2 = e1.X();
// No way José.
E e3 = 0.X();
```

That is not an identity, reference or boxing conversion.

The language design principles at work here are first, no nasty surprises. Extension methods are a late addition to the language and the design team wanted to be very careful about not adding situations where they would become applicable in surprising ways.

And second, in the majority of cases C# reasons about the types of expressions from the inside to the outside. That is, when we see `x = y` we analyze the types of x and y independently and then decide whether the assignment is legal. But for typeless expressions that is inverted. For `x = (y)=>{whatever}` we analyze the type of x, then use that to decide if `(y)=>{whatever}` is a legal right hand side, and if so, what type it is, and what type everything inside `whatever` is.  That inversion of the normal order of things leads to some *very* complicated code in the compiler and no one was eager to add yet another case where we'd have to do inside-out reasoning.

Finally, since apparently you are interested in currying, this might be of interest to you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/25/mmm-curry.aspx